# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' when debugging shows there is a group

Tags: python, regex

When writing the following code, the console shows an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The code:

```
req = re.search("([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)", data).group(0)
```

But, when debugging I see that there is a group, and the code continues to run instead of collapsing. For example when data is `"30DIR /Users/user1/Documents/"`, the console outpost an error while debugging shows there is a match: `"30DIR"`.

Comment: `re.search("([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)", "30DIR /Users/user1/Documents/").group(0)` gives `'30DIR'`. Provide runnable code which you claim produces the problem, please.

Comment: You are presumably running that `re.search` line many times for many different `data` strings. For at least one of them, the match fails, so `re.search` returns `None`, which is causing your exception. You might want to investigate why there's no match on one of your `data` values, if you don't expect that to ever happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
req = re.search("([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)", data)
if req:
    req = req.group(0)
```